# CodeIgniter PHP accessing variable declared in a class from function in same class

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to access an array declared in a class from a function within the same class. I've attempted a couple different ways to try to make it work but I'm relatively new to PHP. This is a snippet of my code

```
class Site extends CI_Controller {

    var $dates = array(
        "Task" => NULL,
        "Date1" => NULL,
        "Date2" => NULL,
        "TimeDiff" => NULL
    );

function index() 
{   
    if($this->$dates['Date1'] != NULL && $this->$dates['Date2'] != NULL)
    {
        $this->$dates['TimeDiff'] = $this->$dates['Date2']->getTimestamp() - $this->$dates['Date1']->getTimestamp();            
    }

    $this->load->view('usability_test', $this->$dates);
}
```

I also attempted using the global keyword as such

```
global $dates;
```

And I still receive a "Undefined variable" error regardless. Thanks!

Comment: Which part in specific of the error don't you understand?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want `$this->dates['Date1']` instead of `$this->$dates['Date1']`. Notice the absence of the `$` before `dates`.

As a side note, be sure you're properly extending `CI_Controller` by defining the `__construct()`like this:

```
class Site extends CI_Controller {

    // class properties, etc.

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    // class methods, etc.

}
```

Another thing to note, `var` is deprecated as of PHP5. You'll want to use either `public`, `private`, or `protected` depending on your needs (Edit: assuming, of course, that you *are* using PHP5).

Comment: @PeteJodo: No problem, I'm glad it helped! See my edits above for a couple of other tips/recommendations.

Answer (score 3):

Create yourself a helper class that does what you need here:

```
class MyTask
{
    private $task;

    /**
     * @var DateTime
     */
    private $date1, $date2;

    ...

    public function getTimeDiff() {
        $hasDiff = $this->date1 && $this->date2;
        if ($hasDiff) {
            return $this->date2->getTimestamp() - $this->date1->getTimestamp();
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    public function __toString() {
        return (string) $this->getTimeDiff();
    }

    /**
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDate1()
    {
        return $this->date1;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTime $date1
     */
    public function setDate1(DateTime $date1)
    {
        $this->date1 = $date1;
    }

    /**
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDate2()
    {
        return $this->date2;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTime $date2
     */
    public function setDate2(DateTime $date2)
    {
        $this->date2 = $date2;
    }
}
```

Key point here is that all the details with that range and stuff is inside the class. So you don't need to care elsewhere.

As additional bonus, the `__toString` method helps you to easily integrate this object in your views, because you can just `echo` objects then.

```
class Site extends CI_Controller
{
    /**
     * @var MyTask
     */
    private $dates;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->dates = new MyTask();
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index() 
    {
        $this->load->view('usability_test', $this->$dates);
    }

    ...
```

Better?